# JAVA CV unsatisfied link error

Tags: android, javacv

I want to use javacv library for image processing. but i am facing problem integrating the library in porject. The Log cat gives error on line

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder =
    new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path + "video" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4",
                             320, 480);
```

All other javacv functions work correctly. Only `FFmpegFrameRecorder` gives error. I have followed the `readme.txt`, included `javacv.jar`, and `javacpp.jar` in the libs folder, as well as extracted `.so` files from `opencv-arm`, `ffmpeg-arm` to `armeabi` folder in `libs`.

The logcat error is:

> 08-22 12:46:07.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2408): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1963]:  1581 could not load needed library 'libavcodec.so' for 'libjniavcodec.so' (find_library[1220]:  1581 'libavcodec.so' failed to load previously)

Answer (score 0):

I Have Created new Workspace, Redownloaded all the files and Created new Project and reintegrated all the jar files, Only after that it worked.